# msi installer run script before installation

Tags: .net, installation, windows-installer

I'm creating a new installation package for my web application, so i want to be able to create a new web site and an applicationPool in the IIS before the installation process  starts so the user can choose the newly created website in the dialog (Actually it can be to do anything before the forms in the wizard would be showed).

Is there a way to do this?

With customs actions seems to be impossible since they are excuted after the wizard forms are showed, and with a boostrapper it seems not be the best option since i'm actually not installing anything just executing a script.

Thanks

Comment: "With customs actions seems to be impossible since they are excuted after the wizard forms are showed" - why do you think so? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371626%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Im working with VS 2008 and using a web site installation project to do this and there all the custom actions are executed after the wizard gathers all the information. Can you please explain me a little bit more how to sequence this actions (if i must do it outside VS can u please be a little bit more detailed)?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to create the website and application pool before the installation?

A simple approach is to just populate the dialog with the website name (and other IIS information) and actia; create it during installation based on what the user does in that dialog.

For example, if you have a combo box with websites simply add your website to it. During install you can check if your website was selected and create it if necessary.

Comment: I need to create the site before the installation because the installation wizard only shows the already created web sites, and the installer configures the new installation there.

Comment: You can try using a custom action to add your website as a string in the list or combo which contains the installed websites. It will be added only as an option, it't not installed before the installation starts. During install you can check if your website was selected and install it if it was. The alternative is a prerequisite which installs the website.